# Core Data fetch persistance

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am wondering if someone could clarify the following from Apples Core Data documentation:

> Changes are not reflected until after the controller’s managed object
>   context has received a processPendingChanges message. Therefore, if
>   you change the value of a managed object’s attribute so that its
>   location in a fetched results controller’s results set would change,
>   its index as reported by the controller would typically not change
>   until the end of the current event cycle (when processPendingChanges
>   is invoked). For example, the following code fragment would log
>   “same”:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = <#A fetched results controller#>;
NSManagedObject *managedObject = <#A managed object in frc's fetchedObjects array#>;
NSIndexPath *beforeIndexPath = [frc indexPathForObject:managedObject];
[managedObject setSortKeyAttribute:
                  <#A new value that changes managedObject's position in frc's fetchedObjects array#>;
NSIndexPath *afterIndexPath = [frc indexPathForObject:managedObject];
if ([beforeIndexPath compare:afterIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"same");
}
```

---

What exactly does "would typically not change until the end of the current event cycle" mean? I have this situation in my code but am not really sure if I can 100% rely on my indexes staying the same until I explicitely preform a save on my managed object context. Could the above code be modified, without performing a save to the context, such that it doesn't log "same"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not really sure if I can 100% rely on my indexes staying the same
>   until I explicitely preform a save on my managed object context.

I wouldn't. The "current event cycle" is the current iteration of the run loop.

Comment: +1 The runloop processes so fast (unless you block it) that it's effects in the UI cannot be discerned by the user.

Comment: I suppose i'm confused with why the documentation goes on to provide a code sample that says it should work if it's not something that should be done. If I have similar code in the UITableView delegate moveRowAtIndexPath will that block the run loop until completion?

Comment: I haven't looked up that example in the docs, but I'd say that it's just demonstrating the point, not something that "should work" or "shouldn't be done." The whole thing is just a caution: if you change frc's sort key, the order of the results doesn't change until the run loop completes.